# Am I Talking CRUD, or Something Else?

Tags: php, forms, crud

I've been developing PHP sites with more complexity lately.  Registered users need to be able to interact with the site and submit materials to it via forms, and have control of their own submissions.

In summary:

1. Present forms to users,
2. Form submissions are transformed into pages (views),
3. Users see, edit, and delete their submissions.

I've been going along assuming this is CRUD.  And I know hot to make this work.  But I keep getting the idea there might be another way to look at this.

I want my users to be able to use forms to submit materials and see those forms again when editing their materials.  But if I want them to edit directly from a page -- not a data table -- is there another term or function I should be talking about?

Comment: CRUD stands for Create, read, update, delete. Whether you are providing these functions using a database or a web app, it's still CRUD.

Comment: netcoder: Yes, I know that these things are called CRUD, but I was wondering whether there is another term or set of actions I should be using for this kind of action.  It's hard to form the question, when I don't know exactly what the thing is called.

Comment: @MatthewSchenker You should ask this question on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: loyalpenguin: thanks for the tip.  My question was closed because it is "not constructive."  OK.  Little confused, but I am trying to understand the policies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is exactly CRUD (Create, read, update, delete).  But that isn't a very specific description of what you're trying to implement.  All dynamic websites with user login and registration implement some form of CRUD.

Maybe the term you're looking for is Content Management System?  CMSes are any type of web application that provides the user with a way to manage their created content(thus the name!)

Examples would be Drupal, Wordpress, etc.

Comment: john500: funny you mention CMSs, because I've been exclusively using Joomla for the past three years.  I'm switching to a framework, and that's making me think clearly about each action of creating and retrieving data.  Sometimes, I know what I'm trying to do, but don't know the name for it, which is why I posted this question.  (By the way, what's the deal with getting marked down just for asking a question?  I wanted to vote you up, but can't now).